# Can this be considered the Newton's rings?

Tags: optics, visible-light, experimental-physics, interference, home-experiment

[image: Newton's ring?]
[image: setup]
It can be made by pointing a laser pointer directly to a mirror at low angle and observing the reflection behind the laser pointer. No convex or concave lens needed unlike the Newton's ring experiment we know.

So far, Newton's ring experiments and theories I read only involves a combination of concave and convex lenses, as Wikipedia says: Newton's rings is a phenomenon in which an interference pattern is created by the reflection of light between two surfaces—a spherical surface and an adjacent touching flat surface. The pattern is created by placing a very slightly convex curved glass on an optical flat glass. The two pieces of glass make contact only at the center, at other points there is a slight air gap between the two surfaces, increasing with radial distance from the center.

None of Newton's ring theories I read in Wikipedia or somewhere else involves a laser pointer and a mirror. Is there the same fundamental physics involved in both experiments? Or could it be a completely different thing?

Comment: That's a remarkable picture, a textbook example of Newton's rings! Perhaps the mirror has a tiny curvature? How does it change if you vary where on the mirror you hit?

Comment: As you move the mirror or laser pointer slightly, the pattern moves inward or outward like the waves on water after you throw a rock to it. You can try it yourself using a higher power green laser. 5mw ordinary red laser also work but you need a dark room. Any flat mirrors should work.

Comment: The pattern position is exactly halfway between the laser pointer and the laser reflection.

Comment: ^ If you have the dot separate of the pattern then it certainly isn't the aperture diffraction.

Comment: Yes that's what I got. If the reflection angle is, let's say 10°, the pattern is in the middle or at 5° It gets brighter if the reflection angle between the incoming beam and the reflection from the mirror is lower and reach its peak brightness as zero degree when the laser reflection completely reflected back to the laser source. It fades away as the angle increases and no longer present at approximately 20 degree. The pattern also gets larger if the distance between the laser and mirror is increased.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. Question: “the pattern moves inward or outward like the waves on water after you throw a rock to it” -- is the center staying dark when you observe this, and only the scale of the fringes change, or does the center change from dark to bright too?

Comment: @kkm yes. Everything changes when I move things around. It's sort of like... I don't know. Probably a portal from a sci-fi movie or something. When I slowly increase the reflection angle, it moves outward from the center, it's like all of the rings infinitely comes out from the center, which alternately going dark to bright and so on. When I slowly decrease the reflection angle, the same process happens in reverse until the angle reaches zero degree. Interestingly, the reflected laser dot appears to be on one of those rings.

Comment: First clue: clean the mirror and it will disappear.

Comment: I've already tried with different mirrors no matter how clean or dirty they are. I've also tried it with different laser color. Same result. Those rings keeps appear. Dirty mirror won't make a perfect circular patterns or even imitate the Newton's ring.

Comment: Just another thought: the huge size of the structure suggests the phenomenon occurs in a thin layer (cf. rainbows on bubbles vs usual N. rings--you need a microscope to see the latter). Your laser is powerful; can it be the metallic coating in the back (partially, a little bit transparent)? The interface between the back surface and the coating, maybe? Never seen anything like this!

Comment: In any case, do not drop this on the floor! You've found something interesting, not likely a new phenomenon but rather a novel demo of an existing one, that may eventually get into textbooks. Find someone to help you publish it please, in a local uni or college. Answers here are so varying that a larger community exposure is certainly beneficial. My guess is, journals that target teaching physics would be the most interested in this. And, personally, I am absolutely baffled by the central location of the rings. How does the freaking thing know to divide the angle in half???

Answer (score 1):

The rings are probably not "Newton's rings", though of course they are a related phenomenon.  Probably they are due to scatter at the front and back surfaces of the mirror.

In effect, light scattered from the front surface acts as a point source.  Light scattered from the back surface will also act as a point source. The interference from two point sources, close together and pretty much in line with each other, results in a pattern like that in your photo.

I'd guess that if you examine the pattern closely you'll see that it is composed of speckles, which would support the idea that it's due to scatter from those surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have Newton’s rings due to intrinsic wavefront curvature in your laser beam. Interference between the curved wavefront reflecting from the front and rear surfaces of the glass gives you concentric rings. If everything were perfectly parallel, the interference would coincide with the reflected laser spot, so my guess is that your first glass surface is slightly non-parallel with the metallized surface.

In the textbook example, there is a collimated beam, and wavefront curvature is introduced by a curved surface. In your case, your laser is not quite collimated, so there is intrinsic wavefront curvature. Thus, you can see circular interference fringes with flat surfaces.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. The length of the non-perfectly collimated laser beam acts as a radius of the curved wavefront. Thus, the front of the beam acts as if it is the curved surface of the convex lens sitting on a flat glass surface, or in my case, a mirror.

Answer (score 0):

$\let\d=\delta \let\lam=\lambda \let\th=\theta
\def\half{{\textstyle {1 \over 2}}}$
I'm leaning towards @S.McGrew's proposal, although there are some points I haven't fully understood. I want to suggest a little computation you could test through some measurements.

Let's define

- $S$ distance screen-mirror
- $L$ distance laser-mirror
- $t$ mirror thickness
- $n$ index of refraction of mirror glass
- $\lam$ wavelength.

Neglecting reflection angle (this is a weak point I've still to
explore) you have two virtual images of laser source. The first I$_1$ coming from reflection on the front surface of glass, is placed at a distance $S+L$ from screen. The second I$_2$ (reflection on the rear, metal surface of mirror) would be at a distance $S+L+2t$, but as far as optical path is concerned it must be treated as if it were at a distance $S+L+2nt$.

Consider a point P on the screen, at a distance $r$ from centre C of fringe pattern. Let $\th$ be the angle CI$_1$P so that
$$r = (S+L)\,\tan\th \simeq (S+L)\,\th.$$
The difference between the optical paths from I$_2$ to P and from
I$_1$ to P is
$$\d \simeq 2\,n\,t\,\cos\th \simeq 2\,n\,t\,(1 - \half\,\th^2).$$

If for $\th=0$ (P=C) $\d$ is a multiple of $\lam$ 
$$2\,n\,t = k\,\lam \qquad \hbox{$k\ $ integer}$$
we'll have a maximum in C. The other maxima will be at 
$$\d = 2\,n\,t\,(1 - \half\,\th^2) = (k-k')\,\lam \qquad 
\hbox{$k'\ $ integer}$$
$$\th = \sqrt{k' \lam \over n\,t}$$
$$r = (S+L)\,\sqrt{k' \lam \over n\,t}$$

You could easily test the last formula. A similar formula holds for minima.

Answer (score 0):

It seems similar with Newton's experiment described in Second Book of Opticks, Part IV. He used concave mirrors of 1/4 and 5/62 inch thicknesses and light beam through a hole of the board which corresponds to the hole at the center of the rings on the screen in your drawing. I suppose that there is no special name for these rings but they would be made by the same way of interference.